# Select random element from array and display in textbox

Tags: vb.net

I have a form with a button and a textbox. I also have a text file with the following contents..

```
Bob:Available:None:0
Jack:Available:None:0
Harry:Available:None:0
Becky:Unavailable:Injured:8
Michael:Available:None:0
Steve:Available:None:0
Annie:Unavailable:Injured:8
Riley:Available:None:0
```

When the user loads the form each value of the text file gets stored into an array. This works fine. What i would like to happen is when the button is pressed a random person (name) who has the value 'Available' will be retrieved from the array and displayed in the textbox.

The code i have so far (which stores each item in text file into arrays):

```
Public Class Form1

    'define profile of person
    Public Structure PersonInfo
        Public name As String
        Public status As String
        Public status_type As String
        Public monthsunavailable As Integer
   End Structure

    'Profile List of persons
    Public Shared personInfos As New List(Of PersonInfo)()   'roster data

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'read all infomations of person from file. lines is profile array
        Dim lines() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines(filelocation)

        For Each line In lines
            'Parses the line string, make Person Info and add it to Person List

            'split string with ":"
            If line.Trim.Equals("") Then Continue For
            Dim strArr() = line.Split(":")

            'make Person Info
            Dim pi As New PersonInfo()

            pi.name = strArr(0)
            pi.status = strArr(1)
            pi.status_type = strArr(2)
            pi.monthsunavailable = strArr(3)

            'add Person Info to Person List
            personInfos.Add(pi)
        Next
```

How do i select a random name from the array and display it in a textbox?

Comment: [Random.Next Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.next?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: You should have edited your existing question instead of asking the same question again with more information. You should delete that other question because there's no need for both.  Also, you were told in a comment on that question to use the `Random` class and there's no sign of it in your code. You should already have found it for yourself with a search but if you're explicitly told to use it and still don't then why are we even here?

Comment: I understand I am to use the random class however I haven't been able to find out exactly how I am to implement it for this particular situation.

Comment: I have used the random class before but not in a situation where I want to select random items (names) from an array. I have been trying but just can't seem to figure it out. I'm very new to VB.

Comment: Use the `Random` class to select a random number between 0 and the length of the array.  Use the selected number as the index into the array `personInfos(selectedNumbere)`.  By the way, your `PersonInfo` structure should be a `Class`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this. Try reading the docs!

```
 Private Sub Button1_click (sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
     Dim r As New Random ()
     Textbox1.Text = personinfos(r.Next (0,personinfos.count)).name
 End Sub
```

**Update**

To select only names with status "Available"

```
 Private Sub Button1_click (sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
     'Instantiate a new random variable
     Dim r As New Random ()
     'This is a LINQ query to select all items from the list where a property of the item
     '(in this case , status) is equal to something. 
     'Try changing Available to something else and see what you get
     Dim qr = From pi in personinfos
                      Where pi.status = "Available"
                      Select pi
      'The following line can be simplified as follows
      'Dim i As Integer = r.Next (0,qr.count)
      'Dim s As String = qr (i).name
      'Textbox1.Text = s
     Textbox1.Text = qr(r.Next (0,qr.count)).name
 End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much :-) Would you mind explaining what each line does? Just so I can understand a little better. As said I am very new to VB so a little explanation would be really helpful.

Comment: Done. but you still need to do a lot of research yourself!